# Spring Boot application does not start in CloudFoundry

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I have a Spring boot Application, built with maven, jdk1.8. 
It's using embedded Tomcat and jar packaging. 
I'm using Spring Tool Suite to push the app to CloudFoundry. I get the following messages in console after pushing:

```
[CONTAINER] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner               INFO  At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. 
[CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig             INFO  Deployment of web application directory /home/vcap/app/.java-buildpack/tomcat/webapps/ROOT has finished in 724 ms
[CONTAINER] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol         INFO  Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
[CONTAINER] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool         INFO  Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
[CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina               INFO  Server startup in 814 ms
healthcheck passed
Container became healthy
Exit status 0
[Application Running Check] - Application appears to be running - MY-APP
```

Problem is - no Spring Boot banner, no startup messages from my application - nothing.
If i browse the URL, i just get a 404(which means somehow Tomcat is running!).

I tried

> cf files

but realised this is on Diego, so I tried

> cf ssh MY-APP

and looked in the logs directory - nothing there at all, not a single file.
and

> cf-events

just says that app has started.

The GUI console in CloudFoundry happily reports that its 'Running'
How do i even begin to troubleshoot this?

Manifest.yml

```
---
applications:
- name: MY-APP
memory: 1024M
host: my-app
domain: xxx.yyy.com
services:
- p-mysql
instances: 1
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://<ip_addr>:3306/<db_name>?user=<user_name>&password=<password>
spring.datasource.username = <username>
spring.datasource.password = <password>
spring.thymeleaf.cache: false
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>MyAPP</groupId>
<artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
<version>0.2</version>

<name>my-app</name>
<description>Attempt2</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.M1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

<repository>
    <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
    <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>

</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

main class

```
package com.sa;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyAppApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(MyAppApplication.class, args);
   }
}
```

CloudFoundry env variables

```
{
 "staging_env_json": {},
 "running_env_json": {},
 "system_env_json": {
 "VCAP_SERVICES": {
  "p-mysql": [
    {
      "name": "p-mysql",
      "label": "p-mysql",
      "tags": [
        "mysql",
        "relational"
      ],
      "plan": "pre-existing-plan",
      "credentials": {
        "hostname": "<ip-addr>",
        "port": 3306,
        "name": "db-name",
        "username": "<username>",
        "password": "<password>",
        "uri": "mysql://<username>:<pass>@<ip_addr>:3306/<db-name>?reconnect=true",
        "jdbcUrl": "jdbc:mysql://<ip_addr>:3306/<db-name>?user=<username>&password=<pass>"
      }
    }
  ]
}
},
"application_env_json": {
"VCAP_APPLICATION": {
  "limits": {
    "mem": 1024,
    "disk": 1024,
    "fds": 16384
  },
  "application_id": "<some string>",
  "application_version": "<some other string>",
  "application_name": "my-app",
  "application_uris": [
    "my-app.xxx.yyy.com"
  ],
  "version": "2d5fd7b0-a1c2-4039-8eed-fb6e25772dee",
  "name": "my-app",
  "space_name": "xyz",
  "space_id": "<some string>",
  "uris": [
    "my-app.xxx.yyy.com"
  ],
  "users": null
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: If you're getting Tomcat's 404 then everything is running OK *except your application*; how are your routes configured? What were you expecting the root page to be?

Comment: I haven't configured any routes in Cloud Foundry. My Controller is mapped to `<app-url>/abc` and that returns a 404.

Comment: You shouldn't need to configure CF routes, but you need to show a [mcve] of your application configuration.

Comment: I've added the config files i can think of, rest is default, like Tomcat port is 8080 when i run locally and i haven't changed anything when pushing to CF. At the very least i'd have expected my application to throw errors on the console, but seems like Spring boot is not even initializing (no banner!).What I'm really after is some troubleshooting guidance, not necessarily a solution to my issue here.

Comment: Check the Logs using `cf logs appname`. Restart your app and check the logs to see what is causing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After ploughing away at this for half a day, i found the problem.For the impatient, it was due to this issue 
[spring boot and java buildpack][1]https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4897

I wasn't getting anything from the STS push, so i reverted to CLI.
First,
`mvn clean package`
then 
`cf push -p PATH-to-Jar`
There was an entire trail of error messages (finally! something to look at!), ending with

```
2016-05-14T21:22:46.71+0800 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 83ec77d4-bcc5-4b12-8430-dd0a4d140b22 payload: {"instance"=>"27dc9686-1853-4 465-745e-55e450ee94c4", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", 
"exit_description"=>"2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* 2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* 
Exited with status 1
\n* cancelled\n* cancelled", "crash_count"=>3, "crash_timestamp"=>1463232166690142658, "version"=>"b37907a9-f4d6-4045-987c-f7bddb5e7a5c"}
```

The link above explains the issue and how to resolve it (use the latest java-buildpack (specify with -b switch of cf cli), so if anyone sees this Exception when pushing a spring boot app to cloud foundry, you know what could be the potential issue!

```
ERR Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate 
interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer :org.cloudfoundry.reconfiguration.spring.CloudPropertySourceApplicationContextInitializer
```